# Versioning for private repository GitLab

Tags: npm, gitlab

When I do `npm install`, in `node_modules` I see the same files, in `shared` folder, I only get new files when I delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and do `npm install`. How can I make it work properly and get the last version of the files after each `npm install`?

```
package.json

dependencies: {
  "shared": "git+ssh://git@git.domain.com:group/shared.git#master",
}
```